# Issues with Looping in Pizza Shop Function

Tags: python, algorithm, function, loops, dictionary

I am currently trying to solve a coding problem about a pizza shop. It is meant to take in multiple parameters (ranging from 1 to more than 1) and add up the constant cost of each to return a certain cost. My question is, what is wrong with the current code that it's not able to loop through the data. I made a function, a dictionary, and a for loop to run through the data. All of this is coded in Python.

```
def cost_calculator(*x, wings, drinks, coupon):

total_cost = 0  #variable that holds final cost of order
print(total_cost)

pizza_to_price = {"mypizza":13}
drinks_to_price = {"small": 2.00, "medium": 3.00,"large": 3.50,"tub": 3.75}
wings_to_price = {10:5.00, 20:9.00, 40:17.50, 100:48.00}
toppings_to_price = {"pepperoni":1.00, "mushroom":0.50, "olive":0.50, "anchovy":2.00,"ham":1.50}

for pizza in x:
    total_cost += 13.00
for topping in wings:
    total_cost += wings_to_price[topping]
for size in drinks:
    total_cost += drinks_to_price[size]
for discount in coupon:
    total_cost = total_cost - (total_cost * coupon)
total_cost *= 1.0625

round(total_cost,2)
return total_cost
```

Re: The error I was getting is that there is a NoneType value being returned if I uncomment everything.

[image: Error I'm getting]

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: _what is wrong with the current code that it's not able to loop through the data_ This doesn't tell us much about the problem.  Tell us what the code actually does, and explain how it is incorrect.

Comment: Can you tell us how you call it and what the output is? Or if it gives an error, tell us what the error message is?

Comment: For one thing, special arguments like `*x` should be _after_ the regular arguments, but you have it listed first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a typo, but you forgot indentation:

```
def cost_calculator(*x, wings, drinks, coupon):

    total_cost = 0.0  #variable that holds final cost of order
    

    pizza_to_price = {"mypizza":13}
    drinks_to_price = {"small": 2.00, "medium": 3.00,"large": 3.50,"tub": 3.75}
    wings_to_price = {10:5.00, 20:9.00, 40:17.50, 100:48.00}
    toppings_to_price = {"pepperoni":1.00, "mushroom":0.50, "olive":0.50, "anchovy":2.00,"ham":1.50}

    for pizza in x:
        total_cost += 13.00
    for topping in wings:
        total_cost += wings_to_price[topping]
    for size in drinks:
        total_cost += drinks_to_price[size]
    for discount in coupon:
        total_cost = total_cost - (total_cost * float(discount))
    total_cost *= 1.0625

    round(total_cost,2)
    return total_cost

pizzas = 3
wings = [10, 20]
drinks = []
discounts = [1.5, 2]
print(cost_calculator(pizzas, wings = wings, drinks = drinks, coupon = discounts))
```

Result: `14.34375`

Python functions : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Python map : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/